# Symfony Doctrine - skip faulty entries on em flush

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'd like to skip all the faulty entries when i'm persisting into the database.

the code looks something like this:

```
...
processing a lot of data
...
foreach( $data as $d ){
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entity->setTitle($d['title']);
    $entity->setDescription($d['description']);
    $em->persist($entity);
}

$em->flush($entity);
```

now i need the title to be under 255 chars, which isn't always that way. Can I somehow ignore that entity and flush all others ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way is validate entity before persist.

example:

```
...
processing a lot of data
...
foreach( $data as $d ){
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entity->setTitle($d['title']);
    $entity->setDescription($d['description']);
    if($entity->isValid()) {
         $em->persist($entity);
    }
}

$em->flush();
```

another way is to persist entities one by one and try/catch flush, but you lose in performance

example:

```
...
processing a lot of data
...
foreach( $data as $d ){
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entity->setTitle($d['title']);
    $entity->setDescription($d['description']);
    $em->persist($entity);
    try{
        $em->flush();
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        //error
    }
    $em->detach($entity);
}
```